# Alterar ícon Bootstrap na versão Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Galera eu tenho esse código:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
```

que é um ícone do bootstrap de uma seta para o lado. Eu quero fazer com que quando uma pessoa conectada no site esteja acessando pelo celular, ele exiba esse código:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>
```

ao invés de exibir o outro, alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A melhor e mais simples maneira de se fazer isso, é criar o teu próprio ícone no qual será a **seta para a direita** por padrão em *Desktops* e quando o ecrã for mais pequeno (ou seja na versão mobile) o ícone se transformará na **seta para baixo**. Por outras palavras:

```
<i class="glyphicon meuIcon"></i>
```

```
.meuIcon:before {
    content:"\e092";
}

/* Quando o tamanho do ecrã for igual ou menor a 480px, muda o ícone transformando-o numa seta para baixo com o código e media query abaixo */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .meuIcon:before {
        content:"\e094";
    }
}
```

Exemplo online no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m055Lkfb/

Comment: exatamente da forma que eu queria, só ajustei o width para o 768 q é quando a linha quebra

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o [Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) do bootstrap:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right hidden-xs"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down hidden-lg"></i>
```